# When:manual for some branches

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We would like to have the following logic: run the deploy_qa stage automatically for the master branch but require all other branches to manually run the stage.

```
stage: deploy_qa
except:
  - master
  when:manual
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the job for two jobs under same stage, one for master only which will not be `manual` and another one that will run only on master and it'll be `manual`.
This jobs will never run together (by defining them to run only/except master).

## Example:

```
deploy qa:
  stage: deploy_qa
  script:
    - <deploy qa...>
  except:
    - master
  when:manual

deploy qa master:
  stage: deploy_qa
  script:
    - <deploy qa...>
  only:
    - master
```

To take it to next level you can use anchors (`&`), aliases (`*`) and map merging (`<<`) to prevent code duplication. read more here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#special-yaml-features